# how to pop up a new window from a picture that has some links?

Tags: javascript, php, html

so I put many links in a picture, so after I click the link it move to a new window but it need so many pages so I want to make the new window appear on the same page with pop up. the problem is I can only do for one link only, so the other links in the picture went to the same page. can anyone help me how to do it?

```
<img src="layout_narasoma.jpg" align="right" height="90%" width="90%" alt="layout_narasoma" usemap="#narasomamap">
<map name="narasomamap">
<area shape="rect" coords="19,43,159,232" href="ruangangenset" alt="ruang_genset">
<area shape="rect" coords="183,43,326,232" href="shelter1" alt="ruang_shelter1">
<area shape="rect" coords="405,22,546,97" href="enclosure" alt="ruang_enclosure1">
<area shape="rect" coords="572,22,712,97" href="enclosure" alt="ruang_enclosure1">
<area shape="rect" coords="405,115,840,280" href="tower" alt="tower">
<area shape="rect" coords="870,130,1013,234" href="selter2" alt="ruang_shelter2">
<area shape="rect" coords="762,295,910,375" href="ruangan3" alt="ruang_3">
</a>
```

that's the code of the picture, please help. should I using elseif or javascript or something?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `target="_blank"` to the `area` elements.

Answer (score -1):

try adding a `target=“_blank”`

*code;*

```
<a href="http://www.w3c.org/" target="_blank">W3C Home Page</a>
```

in your case inside **area** elements

*this will help you with what you wanted to achive.*